# Pivot image around center using jQuery's CSS property

Tags: jquery, css, image

Right now I have a moving/rotating car. But when I move and rotate at the same time, the car doesn't pivot around the center.

```
setInterval(function() {
            box.css({
                left: function(index,value) { return newv(value, 37, 39); },
                top: function(index,value) { return newv(value, 38, 40); },
                transform: function(index,value) { return "rotate(" + newr(37, 39) + "deg)"; }
            });
        }, 20);
```

I have tried to divide the width and height of the image on 2 before calling the CSS-property with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

**[Full fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/nCEWu/11/)**